# iOS equivalent to increasing heap size

Tags: android, ios

iOS apps (for the most part) is written in Objective-C, which is a subset of C, and is therefore a data managed language, unlike Android/Java.

In Android, you have the ability to increase heap size by simply adding this one line in the XML android manifest:

```
<application android:largeHeap="true"/>
```

Is there an iOS version to doing something like this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? What do you think it means to increase the heap size and why do you think that would be useful? Mechanically this isn't meaningful on iOS devices as the device will allow you to use as much memory as is available. What are you really trying to do or what problem are you seeing?

Comment: @Jonah, lets say that your application has a feature to download files. But what if the files are too big? I assumed that making the heap size bigger would solve that?

Comment: @EbadSaghar You don't need huge memory in order to download large files. In order to solve this problem, you can use "streaming" (see `NSURLConnection, NSURLSession and NSStream` and other references) which saves your download partially to disk _while_ downloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well in iOS you don't have any control over the memory.

It is all managed by the kernel. So you cannot increase the heap size.

As pointed out in the comments, memory management has a different notion in iOS.

You get as many memory as available but if the app uses to much memory it will be killed by the system.

Now that you explained your goal, you shouldn't download large files into memory, this will cause trouble. Instead you should save it directly to the disk as you get the response.

Comment: @EbadSaghar & meda: Sucks why? You get all the memory which is available on the system. The system even terminates other suspended applications in order to satisfy the current app's memory requirements. There's just no VM in the device. Having a user or the developer set the heap size is a bizarre way to alleviate flaws in the system.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I am not saying its sucks I am saying you cannot. is that why you downvote me

Comment: @meda You should add that there is a different concept in iOS, where the current app gets all the memory available on the system. This can actually be quite hight, I would guess 2/3 of the available system RAM (e.g. 650 MByte on a 1 GByte device).

Comment: @CouchDeveloper fair, I edit it  my post to reflect the points you made

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Apple's "[Memory Usage Performance Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/AboutMemory.html)" for an explanation of how iOS doesn't manage swap space.

> Although OS X supports a backing store, iOS does not. In iPhone applications, read-only data that is already on the disk (such as code pages) is simply removed from memory and reloaded from disk as needed. Writable data is never removed from memory by the operating system. Instead, if the amount of free memory drops below a certain threshold, the system asks the running applications to free up memory voluntarily to make room for new data. Applications that fail to free up enough memory are terminated.

iOS attempts to provide each application with as much of the device's memory as the OS can spare. However each application is limited to the device's physical memory. There is no option to allocated larger blocks and expect them to be swapped to disk as needed.

Manipulating the heap size in iOS is therefore not a meaningful concept. Each app already has the largest heap the OS can provide. Instead apps must attempt to minimize their memory footprint to remain within the available space on the host device. This means purging in-memory caches in response to memory warnings, streaming access to resources on disk (as @CouchDeveloper suggested in a comment), and minimizing the amount of memory used overall.

As an additional complication iOS attempts to keep memory in use. Unused memory is wasted capacity and users may be better served by the OS keeping more applications suspended and in memory rather than terminated. As a result attempting to measure available free memory does not give a meaningful result. As the device runs low on free memory other applications will reduce their use in response to memory warnings or by being terminated completely.

Comment: Although I had already chosen the answer, that was extremely informative.